# Our site's progress so far

Tags: discussion

I was just browsing area51 and just happened to see the metrics (that are tracked by SO) for our proposal as of today. See the image below. Looks like we are doing fine:

**Updated Stats as of Oct 20 (In particular see the rep metrics)**

[image]

Comment: I really wish that SO shares these metrics more with the community directly so that we know what we have to do. See the answers for example as to how we may potentially address some of the above issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!  Totally agree with you on sharing these metrics -- it's really hard to have a discussion when the factors are fuzzy ("bad" domain name, etc).

Answer (score 6):

Hmm, I have noticed that there is a lot of people near 200 rep that have given some very good answers that I missed to upvote [-;

Comment: @mbq: Great idea.  I just went on and bump up a few of those users too...

Comment: @Shane I see it works -- little such users are left.

Comment: @mbq This won't bring us up to the "excellent" threshold though.  We really need more active traffic...

Comment: @Shane I agree; but the user action was quite successful; we have gathered 15 new 200+ users. Now it is time for catchy questions.

Comment: @Shane: whatever happened to the potential marketing budget you mentioned sometime back?  Perhaps it's time to seriously discuss ways to enhance our profile.

Comment: BTW, I remembered that because I was reminded today that INFORMS is coming up in Nov, though I'm not sure that's really the appropriate venue for advertising/sponsorship.  Still, food for thought if there's a budget to be had.

Answer (score 6):

And we have some problems with Google traffic; from unseen moderators' source of ultimate knowledge: 
[image]

We can fix it by posting few (even trivial) questions that are possibly something that (real) people are typing in Google and trying to answer them in a novel and useful way (i.e. not Wikipedia link).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful to try and glean some insight into what factors might influence the SE team.

Answer (score 1):

Fresh news about the site launch -- 90 days means nothing. We will be taken into account in more-less random time, yet faster the more Excellent marks we will manage to get.
Probably the rule of thumb is that the reputation spectrum of users must be suited to survive high (SO-like, see for instance [NTI faq](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) for details) reputation thresholds.

Comment: Why am I not surprised by this development?

Comment: Bummer, but thanks for the update.  BTW, which part of the NTI faq were you thinking of?  Not sure I see anything about thresholds or maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: @ars "What is reputation?", second table. 250+ limits are much higher.

Comment: Heh, I should drop my job and become a clairvoyant: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/ . Wait, I do it already.